# Jest JS Test Coverage Data Not Posting to Code Climate from Codeship

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, codeship, code-climate

I have a Node.js based project in which I am using Jest for .js unit-testing.  I have the `collectCoverage` config setting set to `true` and can see the test coverage table in my local development runs and when the build is run in Codeship.

However, I can't seem to get the setup correct for getting the test coverage data to post to Code Climate to have the results displayed there.

I saved the repo token given in CodeClimate's setup instructions into a Codeship environment variable, as follows:

`CODECLIMATE_REPO_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxx codeclimate-test-reporter < lcov.info`

Given that locally, the Jest collectCoverage saves the `lcov.info` data file in a directory called `coverage` in the root of my project, I also have tried a variation of the environment variable with that path, as such:

`CODECLIMATE_REPO_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxx codeclimate-test-reporter < coverage/lcov.info`

For the installation of the codeclimate-test-reporter node module (`npm install -g codeclimate-test-reporter`), it's not clear to me from the instructions exactly where it should go.  I've tried putting it:

- in the Codeship test settings setup commands section just before the general `npm install` command,
- in the Codeship test pipeline configuration commands section,

I have also tried installing it as a local dev dependency in my package.json.

No combination of the above attempts at setting things up has resulted in seeing anything on the Code Climate side regarding the test coverage.

As a final note about what I've done, I have *not* committed my local `coverage` directory, so it is not included in my Codeship build.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, shortly after posting this question, figured out the problem.

Instead of putting the CODECLIMATE_REPO_TOKEN in the Codeship Environment Variables section directly, it needed to be included in the Codeship Test Pipeline Configuration settings, after the `npm test` command (which is what generates the `coverage` directory). And, you do need to be sure the path to the `lcov.info` file indicates the coverage directory.